# C# Google OAuth2 get email of the user currently login

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-sheets-api

I just recently try Google Apis and totally new to this. i had spent last 2 hour searching how to get the email that allow the access of the API and how to refresh token automatically.

My code are pretty much same as the tutorial

```
class GoogleAPI
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart";

        public GoogleAPI()
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("Secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/Secret_Credentials.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;  
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });

            // Define request parameters.
            String spreadsheetId = "1Jd9NgmnfvJzPtjXw_jNzSUAlOO532mF6ebYyIIle_H8";
            String range = "Sheet1!A:L";
            SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                    service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

            ValueRange response = request.Execute();

            var a = response;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("success");

        }
    }
```

After searching, i assume that my token will automatically refreshed when expired, so i'm left with 1 problem.

**The problem:** How i can get the email of the user that are saved in the credentials.

I'm really new to this, please help me by explaining it really detailed.

---

Thanks to @DaImTo

I finally understand how to add it. 
his tutorial -> http://www.daimto.com/find-users-email-with-google-api/

**The code to make it works.**

First We need to add "email" as scopes and remember to delete your old credentials.

```
static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, "email" };
```

Secondly, create the service for the google plus.

```
// Create Google Plus API service.
var plusService = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});
```

And finally, get the email

```
var me = plusService.People.Get("me").Execute();
var useremail = me.Emails.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you want an email exactly?

access token allows access to the API. Refresh token will update the access token automcatcly when it expires (1 hour) that's what  FileDataStore does.

File data store already saved your credentials in %appData% if I am reading the credPath path correctly.

The only way I know of to get the current authenticated users email is to go though the Google+ api [People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) send me.  You will need to add another scope to your request.

> If using the userId value "me", this method requires authentication
>   using a token that has been granted the OAuth scope
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login or
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me. Read more about OAuth.

code:

Nuget package:

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Plus.v1
```

Code

```
var me = plusService.People.Get("me").Execute();
var useremail = me.Emails.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: The apps will be used by multiple person, and i had to know who's the one inserting data into the spreadsheet. also you said that refresh token will update the access token automatically, so it wont ask user to accept/deny again right?

Comment: use the users login name and send that to "user".  Each users data is stored by that.

Comment: This might help.  http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/  I would avoid using the email if at all possible its a pain.

Comment: can you explain to me how to do that? i know that i send "user" but if i ask input for those, the person can use fake name.

Comment: Doesn't Google Sheet support [change tracking](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?hl=en) in the first place?

Comment: @Martheen, yes but i need it listed as input in cells.

Comment: You are sending "user" check your code.  I have no idea if it supports change tracking sorry.

Comment: then you are going to have to go though the Google+ api

Comment: @DalmTo actually the "user" part are from the quick guide from the google API itself, so i actually don't know what i have to put there. i only started trying the API today. ah so there are no way to know, beside using the Google+ API, if that so, can you give me some guidance about that

Comment: That's why I am trying to explain to you how the client library works I have been working on it for four years.   Check the link I sent you here is another http://www.daimto.com/find-users-email-with-google-api/  Read both Filedata store Demystified and this one and come back if you get stuck.    Happy to help reading my tutorials are going to get you up to speed fast.

Comment: @DalmTo, wow your's tutorial really easy to understand. I'm gonna read all of them now. Also im gonna to put the final code for the question i had